# render some text like the title

Tags: beamer

I have this slide

[image]

and I'd like to have the two word "Duhamel integral" in the quote environment rendered with the same face as the title (bold, dark red) but w/o changing the size wrt the surrounding text.

I could devise a manual solution with `\color` etc, but probably I won't.

Comment: As always on the site you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal, self contained example that others can copy and work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the colour of the frametitle with `\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Duhamel integral}
  
  \begin{quote}
  The convolution integral we have written is known as the {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\bfseries Duhamel integral} some more text
  \end{quote}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you looking for new environment, let be called `Quote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{Quote}[3]%
{\par\vskip 5ex plus 2ex minus 1ex \sffamily\noindent%
 \textcolor{purple}{\large\textbf{#1}}\par\bigskip
 \noindent{#2}\par%
 \medskip\noindent%
 \footnotesize #3
}{\par\vskip 3ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex 
  \noindent\ignorespacesafterend}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Quote}
{Duhamel Integral}
{\lipsum[66] 
    \begin{equation}
x(t) = \frac{1}{m\omega_n}\int\dots    
    \end{equation}
 \lipsum[66]}
{Jean-Marie Constant Duhamel (Sant-Malo, 1797-02-05 -- Paris 1872-04-029)}
\end{Quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]